Evaluation of conditions in VBA (not stopped if false)
Is it really so that VBA (powerpoint in this case) does not stop evaluating a statement containing "AND" if one side is false ?
Example between case 1:
  With ActiveWindow.Selection
     If (.Type = ppSelectionShapes) AND (.ShapeRange.Count = 1)  then 
          ' do things with just one shape selected
     End If
  End With   

and case 2:
  With ActiveWindow.Selection
     If (.Type = ppSelectionShapes) then 
         If .ShapeRange.Count = 1 then 
            ' do things with just one shape selected
         End If
     End If
  End With   

If nothing is selected the first part fails, and the evaluation should stop ?
Or do I misunderstand so that  (false) and (false)  => True and evaluation always will and should evaluate all elements ?
Hope someone can shed some light on VBA logic.

You need to look at case statements, Else If and/or Else.

No, False And False is still False, but VBA evaluates both sides anyway - it doesn't short-circuit it like many other languages do. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015471/does-the-vba-and-operator-evaluate-the-second-argument-when-the-first-is-false

@Paul  Thank you. 12 years ago since this was answered. I didn't know about the term, but do now. Valuable info.
